# I do not want a modal window to appear

Tags: ruby, watir

Im trying upload image. When I click on "Choose image", the modal window is displayed. But i do not want to show this window.

I have to click on "Choose image" because html attributes (to which I upload an image) are not visible for watir, after click on "Choose image" html attributes are visible.

Im using this for upload image to "Choose image" :

```
img_path = File.expand_path('../image/png.png', File.dirname(__FILE__))
```

after this i use this variable(img_path) and i set image to "Choose image".

Now i want take a screenshot but modal window is still here.

I used :

```
1) browser.modal_dialog.close
2) browser.send_keys(:escape)
3) browser.window(:title => Watir::FileField::WINDOW_TITLES).close
```

I tried use all "alerts" commands, which i found at watir.com GUIDES - ALERTS

I found this but it doesn't work as well: `browser.windows.last.use`

I tried to execute some scripts but without response: `execute_script`

So question is. How to block or how to do not show Windows or Browser window after click?. 
Or do we have to change html so that this attribute is visible in html without clicking on "Select Image"? After that we can upload the image without clicking?

[Modal window after a click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xc8M.png)

```
browser.iframe(class: "modalwin").present?
      browser.iframe(class: "modalwin").element(xpath that click on choose image).click
      img_path = File.expand_path('../image/png.png', File.dirname(__FILE__))
      browser.iframe(class: 'modalwin').file_field(path to set file).set img_path
      browser.iframe(class: "modalwin").element(waiting xpath).wait_while_present
      browser.iframe(class: "modalwin").link(xpath that just click on button OK).click
```

This is my code that left the window open. Unfortunately.

This is my first question here so i hope everything will be ok. Thank you for your answers. I hope everything is written here. Otherwise, i will try to write better informations.

Comment: What exactly happens when you click "select image"? Why some html is not visible to watir before and becomes visible after?

Comment: Hello, first of all thank you for your response.
1) When i click on "select image" modal window appears like at picture what i added.
2) Second quesion is hard to answer, but this is set up our gvc modal window. Html is visible after what i click on "select image".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. I hope it help to others.
You need to execute script like this:

```
browser.execute_script(
        'HTMLInputElement.prototype.click = function() {'\
       "  if(this.type !== 'file') HTMLElement.prototype.click.call(this);"\
        '}'
        )

  img_path = File.expand_path(opts[:image_path], File.dirname(__FILE__))
  browser.iframe(class: modal_win).element(:xpath, choose_image).click
  browser.iframe(id: modal_iframe1).file_field(:name, 'data').set img_path
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that what has popped up is neither a "Browser Window" nor an "Alert." It is not even controlled by the browser, but by the operating system. Since Watir can only control the browser, it can not dismiss it.

Watir allows you to upload a file without clicking on the element that opens that dialog box in the first place. So remove the line that clicks the image and just send the image path to the file field element. It should not enforce visibility in order to interact with it.

Comment: So we have to change html attributes in our gvc. Attributes have to be visible, get it. Thank you.
But is here some script closing operating system windows in ruby ?
Sry for my english, i hope you know what i mean.

Comment: No, you do not need to change html attributes. You don't have to open the modal, just use `#set` on the FileField element. That's it.

Comment: But as I said, file field is visible only in GUI. But in html code is visible only after click. If you did not clicked on "Select image", then can't find html attributes because its is invisible. This attribute is dynamic and can be visible after click.

Comment: Are you saying the file field doesn't exist in the DOM until another element is clicked? If it's there, Watir can interact with it regardless of its visibility.

Comment: Hello again, i tried it but without response. File is not uploaded because watir can't see. I'm using this: 
img_path = File.expand_path('../image/png.png', File.dirname(__FILE__))
browser.iframe(class: 'modalwin').file_field(path to set file).set img_path
It can't find file_field path because, like i said its not visible and watir can't handle it. Html attribute which using file_field, is visible after clicking at "Choose image"

Comment: Can we discuss this in the #watir channel on Selenium Slack? (http://seleniumhq.herokuapp.com/) I'm not sure what "path to set file" is, and it would help if you turned on logging (`Selenium::WebDriver.logger.level = :info`) and gave the results.

Comment: Hello, yes we can i just send you notification.